# How is яблони different from яблоки?

Tags: существительные

Consider the first line of the famous song Катюша:

> Расцветали яблони и груши

In English, this line roughly translates to "Apples and pears were blossoming".
However, the plural noun "apples" in Russian is usually яблоки, not яблони as found in the song.
What's the difference between яблоки and яблони?

Perhaps яблони is better translated to something like an uncounted noun "apple", as in "Apple and pear were blossoming".

Comment: Additional note - in Russian, there is a word for apple tree - "яблоня", but there is no word for pear tree. Thus "груши" means both pear trees (in this song's context) and pear fruits (default context).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think **яблони** refers to the *apple trees* while **яблоки** refers to the *apples*.

Comment: *facepalm* I should have just used Google translate.

Comment: @DanielSank I better use www.translate.ru ;-) it is custom tailored for Russian, while Google/Bing just use Monte Carlo :-D

Comment: @Arioch Если не монти карло, то что?

Comment: @IntrepidNomad a specialized engine. It supports much less languages, but recognize more nuances and is not influenced by political flamewars. Previously there were two major engines, ProMT-Stylus and Socrat. I liked latter more, but it ceased to exist. The link to the former is in my comment above. Take different styles of text (poetic, technical, political) and run through both engines to make a comparison